# I want to understand line of a code regarding linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list

Everytime I study lists ,I encounter the same line in the code regarding linked lists implemented in C language.I dont understand the way I should the following part of the code:

```
 Node*temp=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node))
```

What I understand is : `malloc(sizeof(struct Node))` means that we ask the memory to create a memory block and as argument we insert the number of bytes that we want in the block.Awesome.I get that.

But what does `'Node*temp'` mean? I understand temp is a pointer to node variable but which node  does it point to?
Also what does `(Node*)` mean in front of `malloc(sizeof(struct Node))`

What does `Node*temp=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node))` mean as a whole?

Comment: `Node *temp` is a variable definition like `int *ip` is a declaration of a pointer to `int`.  The `=` is the start of the initialization of the variable.  It can also be effective to use: `Node *temp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(*temp));` and there are plenty of people on SO who excoriate those of us who use the cast (in C++, it is necessary; in C, it is not).

Comment: The cast `(Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node))` formally converts the `void *` returned by `malloc()` into the `Node *` required by `temp`, but the conversion would happen automatically in C (but not in C++). If you compile your C code with a C++ compiler, the cast is necessary; if you only use a strictly C compiler, then the cast is not necessary. Opinions differ on the extent to which the cast does harm; it depends, in part, on the coding standards you use. If you compile with GCC and `-Werror -Wmissing-prototypes`, you won't have `malloc()` undeclared, which is the primary source of concern.

Comment: nice answer, why don't you post it as an answer

Comment: If you make your terminology more precise, things will begin to become intuitive.  For example, you don't "ask the memory to create a memory block".  You call the `malloc` function to "ask" the C-runtime memory allocator to reserve a chunk of memory for you.  You also don't "insert" arguments to functions.  You pass or provide them.  (I am just clarifying, not criticizing!)

Comment: @indiv I understand  but english is not my native language and I have some problems but Im working on it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`temp` points to the space you've created.  It simply contains the address of the beginning of the block of memory you created with `malloc`.

The `(Node*)` in front of the `malloc` is a cast.  `malloc` creates a void pointer `(void *)`, so `(Node*)` is included to convert it to the `Node` pointer, so that the types match and it can be assigned to `temp`.

The whole statement means "make a block of memory of the size of a `Node` variable, treat it as a pointer to a `Node` variable, and save the location in `temp`."

Comment: "`(Node*)` is included to convert it to the Node pointer, so that the types match and it can be assigned to temp." - the answer is tagged `c`. In C, the cast is pointless (and maybe even harmful, but I don't want to get into that). An object of type `Node *` can be assigned from an object of type `void *`.

Answer (score 2):

`Node *temp` points to a memory address.  That memory address is where the memory was allocated from the `malloc` call.  It doesn't necessarily mean a `Node` is located at that memory address, however enough space was created in memory at that location to hold a `Node`.  The `temp` pointer can be used later on to access that memory location.

Answer (score 0):

> What does `Node*temp=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node))` mean as a whole?

Declare a variable named `temp` of type `Node *`.  Use `malloc` to set aside space for a single instance of `struct Node`, and assign the resulting pointer to that memory to `temp`.

Here's a picture:

```
temp                        struct Node block on heap
+---+                       +---+---+---+---+---+
|   |---------------------->|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+                       +---+---+---+---+---+
```

Note that `temp` only exists as for the lifetime of the enclosing function, but the memory it points to will remain allocated until explicitly deallocated with a call to `free`.

As others have mentioned, the cast is superfluous in C; here's a somewhat cleaner way to write it:

```
Node *temp = malloc( sizeof *temp );
```

The type of the expression `*temp` is `Node`, so the result of `sizeof *temp` is the same as `sizeof (Node)` (the parentheses are required if the argument is a type name).  This helps guard against situations where you have code like

```
T *ptr;
/**
 * many lines of code here
 */
ptr = malloc( sizeof (T) );
```

and you decide to change type `T` to `Q`, but you only remember to do it for the declaration of `ptr`:

```
Q *ptr;
/**
 * many lines of code here
 */
ptr = malloc( sizeof (T) );
```

If `sizeof (T)` < `sizeof (Q)`, you'll have problems.  OTOH, if you write

```
ptr = malloc( sizeof *ptr );
```

you'll always allocate the right amount of memory. The general form for an arbitrary type `T` is

```
T *p = malloc( sizeof *p * number_of_elements );
```

If you're writing C++, you should use the `new` and `delete` operators instead of `malloc/calloc/realloc` and `free`.  Yes, there are people who like to have their code compile as both C *and* C++, but I'd rather treat the two as completely different languages (because they *are*).